# Use AsyncTaskLoader and CursorAdapter for network tasks?

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, android-cursoradapter, android-loadermanager

I just digged into the [Loader API](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/listview.html#Loader) and using `CursorLoader` and `AsyncTaskLoader` to populate and manage `ListViews`. My data comes from an JSON API endpoint, so I am using Retrofit to perform network tasks, currently using `AsyncTask`.

Does it make sense to reimplement this in `AsyncTaskLoader` and using a `SimpleCursorAdapter` instead? Because right now it does not to make sense, I have no Cursor, since my data is not backed by `ContentProvider` as it would be the case for instance when accessing a database or similar.

Should I just stick to `AsyncTask` and `ArrayAdapter` or is there a way to use the new API?

Answer (score 1):

Using the AsyncTaskLoader is a good idea.  You might not have to use a SimpleCursorAdapter, rather use the default ArrayAdapter or build a custom Adapter that suits your needs.  Cursors aren't required since your data isn't backed by a ContentProvider.

By implementing a custom Array Adapter, you can also achieve custom filters in your ListViews

Answer (score 0):

Using Retrofit you don't need to worry about AsyncTasks and Loaders - Retrofit already supports asynchronous execution out-of-the-box. You can declare Retrofit's method with a Callback as a last argument.

```
@GET("/user/{id}/photo")
void getUserPhoto(@Path("id") int id, Callback<Photo> cb);
```

And then all you need to do is to create Adapter with received list and set this Adapter to your ListView.

Also Retrofit's method can produce RxJava Observable. This is also asynchronous operation. You can read more on this topic [here](http://blog.danlew.net/2014/10/08/grokking-rxjava-part-4/).

Regarding your question about Adapters you don't need to use CursorAdapter since the source of your data is not SQLite database or ContentProvider

Comment: you still have to create a separate thread to get it on the non-Ui thread even with retrofit 2.0